# Hover preview over excel image link

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I wanted to know is it possible to preview image links by hovering mouse cursor over image urls in excel, or google sheets, or any spreadsheet editor.

Comment: The question doesn't follow the guidelines on [ask]. I.E. it is too broad.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You made me curious, so I looked into this.

The answer is, yes - it requires a bit of VBA and is a bit hacky, but here's how you can do it.

First of all, doing anything on cell hover in excel is a bit hacky.

To do so, we use the `HYPERLINK` formula of a cell.

`=HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("http://i.imgur.com/rQ5G8sZ.jpg"),"http://i.imgur.com/rQ5G8sZ.jpg")`

In this case, I have the URL of a grumpycat picture in my formula.

I also pass this link to a function I create called `OnMouseOver`

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String)
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 75
            .Height = 100
        End With
        .Left = Cells(1, 2).Left
        .Top = Cells(1, 2).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function
```

Finally, in order to clear it when we hover away, we have to put some formulas in the other cells near it.

`=HYPERLINK(Reset())`

And the associated function:

```
Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

Results:
[image: Results]

**Edit**

Expanding on this with multiple links.

We can pass a cell reference along with this to do this with multiple links and have them appear next to the cell.

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 200
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function

Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

[image: Results2]

Comment: lol I love that the cats. That was some clever coding thanks brother help me out alot

Comment: is there a way to quickly add formula to links when you have multiple links in a cell

Comment: I'd need to see your data to know what you're trying to do. Might be worth posting a new question

Comment: really nice VBA, but the multiple links edit one isn't working for me, while testing it out, I noticed that the "TheCell As Range" was the problem, couldn't fix that :/

Comment: You have to add a reference to the cell to your `HYPERLINK` code. Basically use `HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("http://url.to.image",A1),"Hyperlink Text")` where `A1` is the cell that you put the code in.

Comment: @user1274820 oh, it worked! thank you very much! as always I think about the messy possibilities before the simple ones, thought was something on VBA... -.-'.
I didn't even thought that his script could accept references and the Excel yesterday wasn't even showing the #VALUE! error on the cells, only today... would have been a great opportunity to tip me about the error..., but well, my fault after all since its been a long time I didn't updated it. ¬¬'
anyway, I really appreciated your help, thx. =)

Comment: @user1274820 great VBA! I have a question - I am attempting to do the second, multiple links version and I am getting a "Value" error. I tried the comment above - writing it as HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("http://url.to.image",A1),"Hyperlink Text") - where A1 is a URL address of an image. I'm confused what I am supposed to put before the comma there - literally ""http://url.to.image", or something else?

Comment: @StupidQuestionGuy you're supposed to put the link to an image. So if your image is at `http://i.imgur.com/rQ5G8sZ.jpg` you would put that. You can see what is in the cell at the top of the first gif in the post. It's a web address to the image.