# Excel: hover preview over excel image link - Follow Up

Tags: excel, vba

[Hover preview over excel image link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923102/hover-preview-over-excel-image-link)

Hi, All - this is a follow up question on this other question. Proposed solution for multiple URL is not working for me: it just keeps creating screenshots indefinitely. What should I fix so that it only creates one and let me use the other RESET function to remove screenshot?

Help please! 
@user1274820
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274820/user1274820

Example file
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e1478c699e43f1618879468e50006dc120190917130518/74fc7a

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 200
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function

Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

Comment: It should work. It works for me. Could you send one sample of your Excel Workbook?

Comment: Hi @DavidGarcíaBodego , here it is  https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e1478c699e43f1618879468e50006dc120190917130518/74fc7a - it is local image URL's. I appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: That link is not accesible. You should better edit your post and add that screenshot at the end.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Done! :) file is in the post body!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but the link to that image is still not accesible. Try imgur.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Hi, thanks for checking. the goal is to have links to local URL's (offline)

Comment: the file you upload is link to local files so I can not replicate it.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego thanks for checking in. it could be any jpg's. if you get a chance, can you possibly test it for a couple of local jpg's? :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Copy as it is:

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean

Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 200
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function

Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

So in your Workbook, column A, place the route of your file (can be local or URL), on column B place `=HIPERLINK(OnMouseOver(A2;E2);"Link")` (That is for row 2, but you can drag it down) and in column C place `=HIPERLINK(Reset();"Del")`. So the images will appear on column E when you place your mouse on top of columns A and B and you can delete them from the screen just placing your cursor on column C.

Hope it helps.