# Get shape name when mouse over

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to get the name of a shape when move the mouse over this shape?
I know already how to get that on click.

Is it possible to get it on mouse move?

Comment: As there is no mouse over event for shapes, no.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is right. You can just do a tricky issue. Place a hyperlink underneath and you can place an event for it.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego A hyperlink has no mouse over event too, and if it would have one it would not trigger *"underneath"* a shape. Or how did you mean to solve it?

Comment: You can add a screentip to the hyperlink, but you would have to manually type the name of the shape in the screentip. Add the hyperlink to the shape itself, not underneath.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers That makes more sense now.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966771/excel-hover-preview-over-excel-image-link-follow-up)

Comment: So how could we get the name of an activex label when mouse over ?