# How to create a Mouseover for the OLEObjects.Add Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, mouseover

I am trying to move on from a working SUB and change it into a working FUNCTION, I have recently read:
Excel-vba-for-dummies-3rd-edition
and started reading:
Excel_VBA_Macro_Programming-Richard_Shepherd-Mc_Graw_Hill._MS_Excel_2016
and the post on Stack overflow for picture insertion:
[Hover preview over excel image link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923102/hover-preview-over-excel-image-link/43925918)

But the SUB; Function and Hyperlink methods for altering a cell contents are currently bewildering?

What I am trying to achieve; Hovering over a cell shows an OLE object preview (whilst hovering), my example is an AutoCAD drawing object.

My working Sub:

```
Sub DWGPreview()
Dim ol As OLEObject
    Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Test.dwg", _
        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
            With ol
                .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Left
                .Top = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Top
                .Width = 800
            End With
End Sub
```

So, as a little Sub everything seems to work as intended.
When I try to define a function as below, all I get is an active hyperlink if the cell is clicked?

```
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String)
'Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Dim ol As OLEObject
'If Not DoOnce Then
    'DoOnce = True
    Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(URL)
        'With ol
            '.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Left
            '.Top = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Top
            '.Width = 800
        'End With
'End If
End Function
```

Called via (cell A1):

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Test.dwg",A1),"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Test.dwg"), "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Test.dwg")
```

As an update (5-Dec19), the code below works when i step through it but i can't seem to call it via the cell address (HYPERLINK)

```
Public Function OnMouseOver()
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Dim ol As OLEObject
Dim URL As Range
Set URL = Range("A1")
Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=URL, _
        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)

If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
            With ol
                With .ShapeRange
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                    .Width = 800
                End With
                .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Left
                .Top = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Top
                .Placement = 1
                .PrintObject = True
            End With
End If
End Function
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance
S.

Comment: I copied the VBA code exactly as shown in the post you linked to and then entered a similar formula as you showed and it worked instantly. I suggest you to follow the entire instruction in the original post.

Comment: jkpieterse, thank you for taking the time to try the link code and respond, I know it works for the(.Pictures.Insert) method but I'm not working with Pictures! instead I am trying to associate other files with the (OLEObjects.Add) Function, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What precisely are you trying to achieve?

Comment: jkpieterse, Firstly I do appreciate your patience; I have produced a TREE search of all departmental .dwg files (10,500) which reside in many different folder locations, I migrated the results to an excel spreadsheet, where I searched for identical file names, I now want to preview all these files to see there contents, as is the case a matching name does not expressly mean matching content, so after I get the spreadsheet working it will be time to refine the folder structure and drawing content.
My last piece of code works if I step through it, but I cant  get the Hyperlnk formula to work.

Comment: jkpieterse, a plus side to using the preview method, is that it will hopefully help the departmental engineers view the refined files as well as to preview the contents of any excel based drawing register; one thing that may pose an issue for me further down the line, is that not all the engineers will have AutoCAD and I will need to trial a working spreadsheet on computers with Autodesk’s free viewer https://www.autodesk.co.uk/products/dwg/viewers Drawing Trueview, as i believe the package and the OLE function are connected while adding the object to the spreadsheet?

Comment: I think the method you're using can only display a picture object so the files must be of a format that Insert, Picture is able to handle