# How can I insert an image into a cell based off of the displayed value of another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have made a parts router and am attempting to set it up so that depending on the displayed value of cell B3 it will take a .jpg from a specific folder and paste it into the cell with specific dimensions.

The goal is to have the image fill the rest of the available space on a printed page below the cell it is inserted into.

I've been browsing the web for a while trying to find a solution but it seems that my request is too simple or I'm too unfamiliar with the language to be able to ask it properly.

Any and all help is appreciated. For reference I will include an image of my sheet.

[Parts Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spOqN.png)

Comment: Probably needs to be done programmatically, e.g. using VBA.

Comment: Hi Tyler, do you have an example of the path to the file given the value in `B3`? For example, your formula evaluates to `BS-01-02-03-A-01`. What image path would the macro grab?

Comment: Hi user1274820, BS-01-02-03-A-01 would grab the image with the same name, from C:\Users\TylerZumwalt\Pictures\Parts

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using VBA.

To open the VBA Editor, you hit `Alt+F11` with your spreadsheet open:

[image: VBA Editor]

Now we want this code to run when the cell changes, so we select our sheet in the VBA editor by double clicking on it

[image: 2]

Then we choose `Worksheet` and `Change` from the two dropdowns:

[image: i3]

This creates a function that will run [whenever any cell on the worksheet changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change).

[image: worksheet change event]

We want our code to run when cell `B3` changes, so we start by making sure that it did.

We can do this like so:

```
If Not Intersect(Target,[B3]) Is Nothing Then
```

`Target` is whatever happened to change - it can be one cell, or many cells.

By using [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect), we just check to see if `B3` was one of the cells that changed.

To insert an image [we can use this code:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925918/1274820)

```
With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 100
    End With
    .Left = Cells(1, 2).Left
    .Top = Cells(1, 2).Top
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True
End With
```

In the above code, "URL" refers to the path to the image.

If the images are in the same directory as the spreadsheet, we can use `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & [B3] & ".jpg"`

This will take the workbook path, add the necessary `\` to the end of it, then combine `B3` with `.jpg`.

In your example image, this would become `C:\WhateverYourPathIs\BS-01-02-03-A-01.jpg`

Moving through the rest of the code, `LockAspectRatio` ensures that the image doesn't stretch and resize weirdly to fit whatever the dimensions are. We may decide that it's okay for the image to stretch to fill up all the remaining space if we so desire, and we can set this to `msoFalse` ([which is `0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msotristate))

Using `.Left` and `.Top`, we can set the top-left corner position of the image.

Using `.Width` and `.Height`, we can change these dimensions as well.

As for the requirement that it "fill the remaining space", it may be necessary to determine what that space is (and whether or not it will change).

It may also be necessary to choose whether or not we want to stretch it out to fill the space.

So, to put it all together and give you an idea of how this can all be done:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, [B3]) Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & [B3] & ".png")
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 500
            '.Height = 500 'Not necessary when locking aspect ratio
        End With
        .Left = [B3].Left
        .Top = [B3].Top + [B3].Height
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that `B3` in this case is changed by a formula that appears to be altered on a different sheet, so make sure that you capture the change where it needs to be (the worksheet change event only fires for manual user changes).

Results (after changing cell `B3` to `sohelp1` with the image you linked saved in the same directory as my spreadsheet):

[image: final]

A few final notes:

You'll probably want to remove the image should the cell change again.

If there's only one image on the sheet, you can add the line `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete` to the code before you insert a new picture.

You'll also want to make sure that if the actual changes are happening on a different sheet that you reference your sheets accordingly. This just means changing `ActiveSheet` to whatever sheet you want these changes to occur on (and skipping the shorthand `[B3]` type cell references - you can use `Sheet1.Range("B3")` instead to refer to the cell on `Sheet1` (as an example)).

If you have any questions, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you, your reply is very informative and helpful! I appreciate that you took the time and effort to make it so, thank you very much!

Comment: Np - if you need more specific help and can provide a bit more detail I can help 